# Portfolio: Best way to load hidden images for page performance

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my portfolio page the front shows images and name list, if you click on either, you get inside the project, (displayed in the same space). The portfolio images are hidden in the beginning but still loaded. Advantage is, that they are already loaded once you click, disadvantage, they are loaded either way if needed or not and in the end there will be a lot of quite heave imagery which especially on mobile might not be good for the user to have all of it loaded.

Please see the JSfiddle to get an idea of how it works. Is there any way to only load the images (fast enough)on click? Can I somehow save them somewhere else maybe and get a html part in from another side?

https://jsfiddle.net/cvall/zaa69bdc/7/

```
var $Projects = $("#work-right li")
var $titleList = $("#work-left")

var workFunction = function() {
  $($Projects).fadeOut().removeClass("active");
  var selectedProject = $($Projects).eq($(this).index());
  $(selectedProject ).fadeIn(700).addClass("active");
};

$("#base-img").on('click', 'img', workFunction);
$($titleList).on('click', 'li', workFunction);
```

Comment: I would recommend using [JQuery LazyLoad Plugin](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload)

Comment: ah, I did not know it worked on click too, perfect, will try that! Thank you!